# Why would `SeriesCoefficient` not work on an inequality

Tags: series-expansion

Here is a humble function with a series of powers of $x$, but when I express the function as an inequality it is no longer able to solve. Is there a reason for this behavior?

```
SeriesCoefficient[(1 + x + a x)^2/(1 - b x)^2, {x, 0, 1}]
(*2 (1 + a + b) *)
```

versus:

```
SeriesCoefficient[(1 + x + a x)^2/(1 - b x)^2 == 1, {x, 0, 1}]
(*SeriesCoefficient[(1 + x + a x)^2/(1 - b x)^2 == 1, {x, 0, 1}]*)
```

Comment: What is the desired output for various (in)equalities?  `==2`?  `==3`?  `<=3`?

Comment: @Adam for the coefficient with powers of `x^1`, I would have expected that the eqaulity would read `2(1+a+b)==0` as there are no powers of `x^1` on the right hand side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that your example is an equality ([`Head`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) of [`Equal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)) rather than an inequality (`Head` of [`Less`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Less.html) or [`Greater`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Greater.html) or ...). You must [`Map`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) [`SeriesCoefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html) onto the sides of the equality.

```
eqn = (1 + x + a x)^2/(1 - b x)^2 == 1;

SeriesCoefficient[#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ eqn

(* 2 (1 + a + b) == 0 *)
```

**EDIT:** Alternatively, use [`ApplySides`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplySides.html)

```
ApplySides[SeriesCoefficient[#, {x, 0, 1}] &, eqn]

(* 2 (1 + a + b) == 0 *)
```

Comment: Ah I think I understand. So the conceptual problem was that I was thinking of the object `eqn` as a single object, but in reality it is 2 objects displayed by `Object 1 == Object 2` and so we need to map the operation onto both?

Comment: @akozi You can apply the `D[]` operator to an equation directly, `D[x^2 == x^3, x]`, but not `Series`, not `Integrate`, maybe not anything else. I don't know if there is an explanation for the apparent inconsistency. (Interestingly though, while `Integrate[x^2 == x^3, x]` doesn't work, `Integrate[x^2 == x^3, {x, 0, 1}]` does, yet again `Integrate[3/4 x^2 == x^3, {x, 0, 1}]` does not!)